# how to move next and previous billno (fetch from database) and display in the view page using codeiginter

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
 how to move previous and next billno and 
      view in the view page.


   public function Bill_Prev1(){

        $this->db->query('SELECT * from salesitem where billno = 1 AND 
      billno > 1 ORDER BY billno ASC LIMIT 1;')->result_array();
        $this->db->join('salesbill', 'salesbill.no = salesitem.billno','left 
    outer');
        $this->db->join('parmaster','parmaster.Pcode = 
      salesbill.partyname','left outer');
        $query = $this->db->get()->row();
        return $query;
          }

   public function Bill_Prev(){
   $query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from 
  salesitem where billno = 1 AND billno > 1 
     ORDER BY billno ASC LIMIT 1;')- 
   >result_array();


          return $query;
      }
```

this is model code..............

my prblm is how to move previous and next no using codeiginter..........

Comment: are you getting 1st result from above query?

Comment: i am getting first and last bill no when i clicked  next it doesnt move

Comment: in above query you have mention billno= 1 this dynamic or static you have pass billno and you have write diffrent function for next and previous?

Comment: how to write the function to move next and previous

Comment: There is no need to write new function for next and previous you can manage it on the single function you just update your limit offset

Comment: i cant understand and i didnt have no idea........

Comment: Okay im not understand you code. can I give you simple example so it helps you to understand what to do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182701/discussion-between-esakkichandra-and-sachin).

Answer (score 1):

Pass current bill Number and order (next/pre).

```
public function Bill_NextPrev($billNo=0,$order='next'){
   if($order='next'){
      $this->db->where('s.billno >', $billNo);
   }else{
      $this->db->where('s.billno <', $billNo);
   }
   $this->db->limit(1);
   $this->db->from('salesitem as a');

   $query = $this->db->get();
   if( $query->num_rows() == 1 ){ 
     return  $query->result();
   }
   return false;
}
```